# Get statistics on the activity of a Github account in time

Tags: git, github, account

I would like to evaluate the "livelihood" of a software which spans on multiple Github repositories under the same account. In order to do so, I thought I would chart the overall activity of the account in time. The problem is that, while this is possible for single repositories using the tool 'Insights'->'Code frequency" (and "Commits"), I can't seem to find a way or a tool that can do quite the same.
Is it possible to have this same information about an account?

[Example: Code frequency of a repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugN08.png)